# User Input Price within product form tag

Tags: expresso-store, expresso

I've got the following product form tag for adding multiple items (Donations) to a cart but can't figure out how to allow the user to input the price.

```
    {exp:store:product_form}
    {exp:channel:entries channel="{donation_channel}" dynamic="no"}
        {exp:store:product entry_id="{entry_id}" disable_form="yes" }

            <input type="hidden" name="items[{count}][entry_id]" value="{entry_id}" />

            <label class="field_label" for="price">{donation-description}
            <input type="text" name="items[{count}][item_qty]" value="" />
            </label>

            {/exp:store:product}
        {/exp:channel:entries}

           <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Make Donation" class="button expand" />

{/exp:store:product_form}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `price` input for each item.

```
<input type="text" name="items[{count}][price]" value="" />
```

And of course you need the Store field for that channel set to allow user prices.

Comment: Thanks Derek.

Store field {donation-donation} is set to allow user prices. Added name="items[{count}][price]" to inputs but now not adding anything to cart.

Comment: You added  a *new* input for the price, correct? Is your `item_qty` a separate input and a positive integer?

Comment: Ah now I'm with you Derek. added an input with price and all good.

Just wondering I don't rurally want to show the quantity but I guess I have too. If I give it a value then all the donations get added with that qualtity.